# Coloring line segments in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have following data for a student's score on a test.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(question = 0:10,
                 resp = c(NA,sample(c("Correct","Incorrect"),10,replace=TRUE)), 
                 score.after.resp=50)
for (i in 1:10) {
  ifelse(df$resp[i+1] == "Correct",
         df$score.after.resp[i+1] <- df$score.after.resp[i] + 5, 
         df$score.after.resp[i+1] <- df$score.after.resp[i] - 5)
}
df
```

.

```
   question      resp score.after.resp
1         0      <NA>               50
2         1   Correct               55
3         2   Correct               60
4         3 Incorrect               55
5         4 Incorrect               50
6         5   Correct               55
7         6 Incorrect               50
8         7 Incorrect               45
9         8 Incorrect               40
10        9 Incorrect               35
11       10   Correct               40
```

I want to get following graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x = question, y = score.after.resp)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

My problem is: I want to color segments of this line according to student response. If correct (increasing) line segment will be green and if incorrect response (decreasing) line should be red. 
I tried following code but did not work:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = question, y = score.after.resp, color=factor(resp))) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would probably approach this a little differently, and use `geom_segment` instead:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(with(df,cbind(embed(score.after.resp,2),embed(question,2))))
colnames(df1) <- c('yend','y','xend','x')
df1$col <- ifelse(df1$y - df1$yend >= 0,'Decrease','Increase')

ggplot(df1) + 
    geom_segment(aes(x = x,y = y,xend = xend,yend = yend,colour = col)) + 
    geom_point(data = df,aes(x = question,y = score.after.resp))
```

[image]

A brief explanation:

I'm using `embed` to transform the x and y variables into starting and ending points for each line segment, and then simply adding a variable that indicates whether each segment went up or down. Then I used the previous data frame to add the original points themselves.

Alternatively, I suppose you could use `geom_line` something like this:

```
df$resp1 <- c(as.character(df$resp[-1]),NA)
ggplot(df,aes(x = question, y = score.after.resp, color=factor(resp1),group = 1)) + 
    geom_line() + geom_point(color = "black")
```

Comment: First, thanks for showing embed function. I was doing such staff in a longer way.. I thought about line_segment but I cannot handle it like you did. Perfect, thanks for solution.

Comment: Hi @joran Is it possible to do this with `geom_line`?

Answer (score 11):

By default ggplot2 groups the data according to the aesthetics that are mapped to factors. You can override this default by setting group explicitly,

```
  last_plot() + aes(group=NA)
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the question of which segments to colour, however. @joran's answer has the right approach.

Comment: Well, actually this is what I was looking for originally, and after your solution I thought I should change my data structure.  Thanks for showing override option..

Comment: @baptise I actually tried to change data structure a little bit. Put `NA` at the end of `df$resp` instead of start like: `resp = c(sample(c("Correct","Incorrect"),10,replace=TRUE),NA)` solved my problem as well. :)