# How can I specify the color my line graph based on this specific condition?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an R script which pulls stock prices from Yahoo Finance. There are no issues with the R codes and they run just fine.

Here is an extract of my R codes and its output:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(ref.date = as.Date(ref.date)) %>%
  arrange(ticker, ref.date) %>%
  group_by(ticker) %>%
  mutate(ticker = paste(ticker, round((last(price.close) - 
                                         first(price.close))/first(price.close) * 100, 2), '%'), 
         label = replace(round(price.close,2), -c(1, n()), '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ref.date, y = price.close, label = label)) + 
  geom_line(size=1, color="blue") + geom_text(size = 3, fontface="bold") + 
  facet_wrap(~ticker, scales = 'free_y')
```

Output:

[image: output]

However, I want to modify the line color of my charts based on the following condition: If the % change is negative (in this case, HUYA -40.14%), then the line color must be RED, else it must be BLUE for the rest.

Any help will highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coloring line segments in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071486/coloring-line-segments-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Thanks for pointing towards this answer. However I am confused as how to implement this in my scenario. The answer relates to coloring "segments" of a line. In my case, It is the FULL line that needs to get colored in RED.

Comment: this is why you should post a fully reproducible example. So for us to be able to actually understand your problem. (and for future people to be able to learn from this problem).

Comment: (Therefore also my downvote, just in case it was not clear why - check also https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ and https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should colour the whole line, but without the data, I can't check.

I made `change` as a separate column for clarity and added lines at the end to give the correct colours and remove the guide.

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(ref.date = as.Date(ref.date)) %>%
  arrange(ticker, ref.date) %>%
  group_by(ticker) %>%
  mutate(change = last(price.close)/first(price.close) - 1,
         ticker = paste(ticker, round(change*100, 2), '%'), 
         label = replace(round(price.close,2), -c(1, n()), '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ref.date, y = price.close, label = label)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = ifelse(change >= 0, "blue", "red")), size = 1) +
  geom_text(size = 3, fontface="bold") + 
  facet_wrap(~ticker, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  guides(colour = "none")
```